# How to bind tool tip in drop down list in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to bind tool tip to drop down list item.
My code is

```
protected void ddl_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["HeadToolTip"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = ViewState["HeadToolTip"] as DataTable;
        DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;
        if (ddl != null)
        {
            foreach (ListItem li in ddl.Items)
            {

                DataRow drow = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Field<string>("HeadCode") == li.Value.ToString());
                if (drow != null)
                {
                    li.Attributes["title"] = drow["ToolTip"].ToString();// li.Text;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is working but after selection of any item tool tip is removed from all item list.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting tooltip on `DataBound`, it might be possible when you are not binding Data within Load or `SelectedIndexChange`, when you select an item, 2 things occur, `SelectedIndexChange` event fires and then Page_Load event fires, you are not binding in either one of them I think. That's why somehow, `tooltip` not working. You should place your `tooltip` code within a function and call that function from Page_Load or `SelectedIndexChange`, so the `tooltip` will again be binded with `DropDownList`

Hope it solves your issue.
Regards!